# Leaking hose from new bathroom faucet

Tags: leak, faucet

I bought a new faucet by Glacier Bay.
The faucets has 2 hoses attached to it.
I tightly connected the hoses to another hose using a male-to-male adapter.
When i turn the water on i see water leaking, but it looks like its leaking from the hose end joint. Not where the actual connection is.

Coukd this be a defective product?[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong fitting to connect those two hoses. It looks like the end of the fitting attached to the hose on the fixture is correct, but the end attached to the hose to the water supply is not correct. Take the supply hose and the 
connecting fitting into a plumbing supply and ask what connector is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Those are o-ring connectors and shouldn't be installed "tightly". You've probably damaged the rubber or deformed the metal. Take them apart and have a look.

They should be tightened hand-tight plus maybe a turn.

Comment: Which ine is o ring, the silver or the gold piece?

Comment: Neither. It's between the two. You can see it [here](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/images/slip-joint-example.jpg).

Comment: I would call this rubber seal a cone seal. It may be designed to fit *inside* the fitting it attaches to, so the connecting fitting might not be a male-male, but a female-male or female-female.

Comment: I agree with @isherwood, regardless of style (o-ring or cone seal, both are common) the fittings at the end of these flex hoses are not designed to be tightened like other threaded fittings. OP has overtightened.